# find the highest number from hardcoded users

Tags: javascript, class, object

I was trying to determine which car a store sold the most. I've used some hard-coded data and my coding so far looks like this.

I would like to sort from the three cars which one was sold the most of. I was trying to use math.max but I'd like the name of the car to appear as well. Any tips on what type of coding I should use?

```js
class carbought{
    constructor(name, carsbought){
        this.name = name;
        this.carsbought = carsbought;

    }
}
let car1 = new carbought('skoda', 32)
let car2 = new carbought('fiat', 42)
let car3 = new carbought('volvo', 52)

var arr = (car1, car2, car3);
const = indexofarray = arr.indexof(Math.max(...arr));
var max = math.max.apply(math, arr);
console.log(max, indexofarray);
```

Comment: Post the code that you attempted.

Comment: See [How to sort an array of objects by a property value in JavaScript](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-sort-array-of-objects-by-property-javascript/).

Comment: Prerak ive edited my post now

Comment: You could [sort the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and take the first/last element.

Answer (score 1):

```
let cars = [car1, car2, car3];
let sortCars = cars.sort((carA, carB) => carA.carsbought - carB.carsbought)
```

Comment: makes sense but shpuld i do this without the mathmax